# AWS ALB Request Count Per Route

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-application-load-balancer

I want the Requests Per Unit Time at route/path level metrics from AWS Lambda.

For example, path = `/admin/options`, Requests Per Second = 200.

My application supports many routes like this

I have looked into documentation but the Requests per unit time is not at route level.

Comment: You would have to parse this out from the request logs, unless each route has a different target server or Lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out, you have to do it by analyzing [ALB access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html). This process is much simplified as **Amazon Athena** can query the ALB's logs directly in S3 as explained in [Querying Application Load Balancer Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/application-load-balancer-logs.html).

This means that you don't have to download the logs before processing, or write any custom processing application. Instead you can run Amazon Athena queries against the logs.